# Soundcloud oembed not working on mobile devices

Tags: soundcloud

When using the soundcloud oembed widget on android devices URLs of the form http://soundcloud.com/oembed.json?auto_play=true&maxheight=166&url=... are getting redirected to http://m.soundcloud.com/oembed.json?auto_play=true&maxheight=166&url=.... Unlike the http://soundcloud.com/oembed.json responses, the m.soundcloud.com responses do not include the following header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

This causes errors such as the following:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://soundcloud.com/oembed.json?auto_play=true&maxheight=166&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2Fplasticworld%2Fsavoir-eternal. The request was redirected to 'http://m.soundcloud.com/oembed.json?auto_play=true&maxheight=166&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2Fplasticworld%2Fsavoir-eternal', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.
```

Ultimately this leads the oembed to fail.

Is it possible to look into this, please?

Thanks,
Simon

Answer (score 2):

This should be fixed now. Thanks for the report.
Arbo